# Record Processing If Record Exists UPDATE, INSERT in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, insert

```
I have three tables:

CUSTOMER                   Columns (Tracking)                            
Reference              Columns (Ref_Tracking, Project)
PROJECT                     Columns(Project)
```

I need to check Reference to see if records in a column (Tracking) from CUSTOMER exist in Reference (Ref_Tracking).  Then Check if the associated record from Reference (Project) Exists in PROJECT (Project).

```
If they exist UPDATE PROJECT 
SET PROJECT.NAME = CURSOR VARIABLES 
        ETC
        ETC

If they do not exist
INSERT INTO REFERENCE
VALUES (CURSOR VALUES)
```

I have a cursor that is looping through with all the variables for Customer Table.

I have tried below but no data is being populated I am not sure what I am doing wrong, Or if there is a better way to do it.  Im learning pl/sql so not sure if I am on the right track.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P1
    AS
      V_NAME            CUSTOMER.NAME%TYPE;
      V_TRACKING        CUSTOMER.TRACKING%TYPE;
      V_ADDRESS         CUSTOMER.ADDRESS%TYPE;
      V_CITY            CUSTOMER.CITY%TYPE;
      V_STATE           CUSTOMER.STATE%TYPE;
      V_NUMBER          CUSTOMER.NUMBER%TYPE;
      V_ Ref            Reference.REF_TRACKING%TYPE := NULL;
      V_Project         REFERENCE.PROJECT%TYPE := NULL;
      V_Project_2       PROJECT.PROJECT%TYPE := NULL;

      CURSOR C01
         IS
            SELECT  C.Name,
                    C.Tracking,
                    C.Address,
                    C.City,
                    C.State,
                    C.Number
              FROM  Customer
             WHERE  C.Number = Another_Table;
    BEGIN
      FOR fetchc01 IN C01 
      LOOP
        BEGIN
          Select Ref_Tracking, R.Project, P.Project
            Into V_ Ref, V_Project, V_Project_2
            From Customer C, Reference R, Project P
           Where R.Project = P.Project
             AND Tracking = Ref_Tracking;
        EXCEPTION
           WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS
           THEN
              NULL;
           WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
           THEN
              NULL;
        END;

        BEGIN
          IF V_Ref = fetch01.Tracking
          Then 
            Insert Into Sample_Project
              VALUES (V_Name, V_Tracking, V_Location)
        END
     END LOOP;
   END;
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: The procedure compiles but it doesnt return any data on the inserts or updates.  Wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it or what I am doing wrong.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This query

```
Select Ref_Tracking, R.Project, P.Project
  Into V_ Ref, V_Project, V_Project_2
  From Customer C, Reference R, Project P
 Where R.Project = P.Project
   AND Tracking = Ref_Tracking;
```

is inside the loop but it does not depend on anything that changes from one iteration of the loop to another.  That seems highly unlikely to me.  Either the query should be moved outside of the loop or, more likely, you are missing some predicate.  Perhaps you want something like

```
Select Ref_Tracking, R.Project, P.Project
  Into V_ Ref, V_Project, V_Project_2
  From Customer C, Reference R, Project P
 Where R.Project = P.Project
   AND Tracking = Ref_Tracking
   AND tracking = fetchc01.tracking;
```

Additionally, your exception handler

```
   EXCEPTION
       WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS
       THEN
          NULL;
       WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
       THEN
          NULL;
```

is saying that you you're perfectly happy if your query returns 0 or more than 1 result to have the values of your local variables `V_Ref`, `V_Project`, and `V_Project_2` be undefined or NULL.  That also seems unlikely.  I would wager that the query as written always returns multiple rows and that this is actually what you expected so your exception handler is swallowing your exception.  That, in turn, means that your code runs, doesn't do what you expect, and doesn't throw any errors.  You would likely be much better off in this case removing the exception handler entirely and letting your code throw an exception if it encounters an error.  At least that way, you have some information to use to debug the problem.  Exceptions should only be caught if you can do something useful with them or if you really are perfectly happy ignoring the error.